# Allow access from single URL in htaccess when using wget inside an Github action

Tags: .htaccess, github-actions

So this is the htaccess i'm using:

```
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from .github.com
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
<RequireAll>
Require all denied
Require expr %{HTTP_HOST} -strmatch '*.github.com'
</RequireAll>
</IfModule>
```

and this is inside the Github action:

```
Run echo ${{ github.server_url }}
  echo https://github.com
  wget -P ./copy/it/here https://www.myurl.com/repo/mypackage.zip
  unzip -qq -o ./copy/it/here/mypackage.zip -d ./put/it/here
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}

https://github.com
--2023-06-08 19:29:12--  https://www.myurl.de/repo/mypackage.zip
Resolving www.myurl.com (www.myurl.com)... 123.123.123.123, 2a00:1169:103:b440::
Connecting to www.myurl.com (www.myurl.com)|123.123.123.123|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2023-06-08 19:29:13 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

Is the htaccess wrongly formulated?

Comment: Which of the two blocks is applying - the `!mod_authz_core.c` one, or the other? You are not checking the same thing in those two. `Allow from .github.com` means the host this request _originates from_, needs to match `.github.com`. `%{HTTP_HOST}` is the name of the server this request is _going to_.

Comment: Hi. those two blocks are for different apache versions and the plan is to formulate the same in both. So it seam the one in RequireAll is wrong. 
How would it look to allow the request from?

Comment: The equivalent to the originating host name used with `Allow from`, would be the `REMOTE_HOST` environment variable.

Comment: No help so far.

Comment: You might need to configure https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#hostnamelookups as well.